# Unknown part fell out of my motorcycle

Tags: honda, motorcycle, battery, part-identification

So I was taking the battery out of my bike (99 Honda Shadow 750 ACE) to ship it this past December, when two parts of the bike I'd never seen fell out from somewhere near the battery case. They sort of look like hair curlers and I suspect maybe they were wrapped around the battery cables? (See the photo)

[image: unknown part]

Any guesses as to what they might be are appreciated!

Comment: Are they plastic or metal?  If metal does a magnet stick to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are definitely devices for holding hair in place. [image]

As for what purpose (if any) they were serving in your motorcycle, one can only guess!

Comment: This is hilarious.

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty confused as well.  The guys over at the Honda shadow forums are having a good laugh too.

Answer (score 4):

My first thought is that they are a spacer or shim to prevent the battery from sliding back and forth in the battery box.

Comment: Not knowing either, this was long the idea of my first thought as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; battery case seems secure.  The guys over at the Honda Shadow forums don't recognize the part and figured it was added by a previous owner to secure the battery cables.

Comment: @neanderslob, no judgment here. I have to secure all kinds of cables all the time and I've made much dumber choices than a couple of hair spin pins!

Comment: @BobCross Lol, glad to hear it!  This question still gives me a laugh.